# Stripping CGI.HTTP_REFERER and CGI.SCRIPT_NAME in Coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, stripping

I have the block of code below which runs a query and checks for an existing record and runs a second insert query if no record is found.

```
<cffunction name="EndRequestFunc" access="public" returnType="string">
   <!---Queries Table To Get Requested Record--->
    <cfquery name="qryGetPageRecord" datasource="First_Main_Dev"   
    dbname="First_Services_Dev">
    SELECT pageName 
    FROM tblCFMPageRequest
    WHERE pageName = '#CGI.HTTP_REFERER#' AND scriptName = 
    '#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#'
    </cfquery>
    <!---Conditional Check for record count equal to 0--->
    <cfif qryGetPageRecord.recordCount eq 0>
    <!---If record count equal to 0, recordset query executed--->
    <cfquery name="setNewRecord" datasource="First_Main_Dev" 
    dbname="First_Services_Dev">
    INSERT INTO tblCFMPageRequest
    VALUES ('#CGI.HTTP_REFERER#', '#CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#')
    </cfquery>
    </cfif>
    </cffunction>
```

What I need to do is strip the values of the two CGI variables of all formatting so that a value like this **"example.com/portal/mypage.cfm"** will be stripped of http and everything else down everything to just **mypage.cfm** before its inserted by the query. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Update: Thank to the advice given, I was able to eliminate the http://example.com/ portion of the URL using the ListLast function. 
I was short sighted in not remembering my urls have characters that need to be eliminated after the "cfm" point. Here is one of my actual results from ListLast: client_modify.cfm?uid=248&al=1&a_trigger=1.

I've tried using some other List functions in Coldfusion to no avail as of yet. Any advice on how to eliminate the bold portion of:
 client_modify.cfm **?uid=248&al=1&a_trigger=1** so I'm just left with a clean client_modify.cfm

Comment: Keep in mind that `HTTP_REFERRER` and `SCRIPT_NAME` can be spoofed, so this information may not always be accurate.

Comment: As a related thought to the original question, how can I strip everything after the page name? My code is working to strip everything prior to the page name. I didn't think ahead to remember that the pages which need to be logged have parameters coming after the page name. Is there a way to trim what comes after the page name as well? Below is a result from my current code: 

            user_modify_view.cfm?uid=248&al=1&comp_id=100.  
I now need to look at stripping everything after .cfm

Comment: @Alex - Same concept. Treat it as a list delimited by "?".

Answer (score 4):

Use `ListLast()` function with `/` as a delimiter. Also, always try to use `cfqueryparam` to put values in queries. Like this.

```
<cfquery name="setNewRecord" datasource="First_Main_Dev" bname="First_Services_Dev">
    INSERT INTO tblCFMPageRequest
    VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ListLast(CGI.HTTP_REFERER,'/')#">, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME,'/')#">)
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I usually use cfqueryparam on my variables. I just forgot to this time. Great reminder.

Answer (score 3):

CGI variables shouldn't have any "formatting", so your question is a bit confusing.

If you're just looking to get the filename at the end of the string, you can use the list functions.

```
fileIwant = ListLast(CGI.SCRIPT_NAME,"/");
```

If `CGI.SCRIPT_NAME` is `/wwwroot/example/index.cfm`, `fileIwant` will result in `index.cfm`.

Have a care with the referrer, as it may not be defined and parsing it out will throw an error.